# Perfect Forwarding fails when (decayed) type deduced from functor class template argument. Why?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

In the example below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
//okay:
//
template<typename T, typename F>
decltype(auto) runner(T&& t, F f)
{
    return f(std::forward<T>(t));
}

//okay:
//
struct runner_t_f {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T&& t)
        {
            std::cout<<"template op(): "<<t<<'\n';
        }
};

template<typename T>
struct runner_t {
    void operator()(T&& t) //error: cannot bind 'T' lvalue to 'T&&'
        {
            std::cout<<"template functor: "<<t<<'\n';
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    int j{13};

    auto res = runner(j, [](int const& x) -> double { //okay
            return static_cast<double>(x*x);
        });
    std::cout<<res<<'\n';

    runner_t_f rtf{};
    rtf(j);//okay

    runner_t<int> rt{};
    rt(j);//not okay...why?
    //error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’

    return 0;
}
```

I try to create these `runner` trampoline functions using perfect forwarding. All compile (and execute) except `runner_t`, which fails with error commented in the code above. Why?

And how could I simulate what the compiler is attempting to do, so that I can understand what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You no longer use forwarding reference in `runner_t`, `T` is fixed by the class.

Answer (score 3):

Forwarding references work due to reference collapsing and template type deduction rules.

In a simple function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) {}
```

- When called as `foo(42)`, `T` is deduced to be `int`, and so `T&&` becomes `int&&`: rvalue-reference-to-`int`.
- When called as `int i = 42; foo(i)`, `T` is deduced to be `int&` and `T&&` becomes `int& &&`.  Since you can't have a reference to a reference, the reference collapsing rules kick in and leave you with `int&`: lvalue-reference-to-`int`.

What this all means is that in this:

```
template<typename T>
struct runner_t {
    void operator()(T&& t) //error: cannot bind 'T' lvalue to 'T&&'
        {
            std::cout<<"template functor: "<<t<<'\n';
        }
};
```

- When you specify `runner_t<int>`, `T&&` becomes `int&&`, and an rvalue-reference can't bind to `j` since it's an lvalue.
- If you instead specified the type of `rt` to be `runner_t<int&>` then the type of `t` would be `int& &&`, which would collapse to `int&`.  That could bind to `j`.

Answer (score 2):

To simulate what the compiler is doing you would need something like this:

```cpp
    runner_t<decltype((j))> rt{};
    rt(j);
```

We need to pass the type of the expression `j` (which we do with the extra brackets). It's an lvalue, so you get `T = int&`, and `T&& = int&`, which we can pass `j` as.

It didn't work before because with `T = int`, `T&& = int&&`, which can only be bound to rvalues, so you would have to do something like `rt(int{j})` (Incidentally, `decltype((int{j})) = int`, so `runner_t<decltype((int{j}))>{}(int{j})` would still work)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the case is clearly documented in "C++ Templates - The Complete Guide", 2nd ed., Josuttis et. al., section 15.6.4, page 283:

"The results of the special deduction rule for rvalue references are very useful for perfect forwarding. However, they can come as a surprise [...].
...this deduction behavior only applies when the function parameter [...] is part of a **function template, and the named template parameter is declared by that function template**. Therefore, this deduction rule does *not* apply in any of the following situations:"

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
   //...
   X(T&& ); //this constructor is not a function template
   //...
};
```